# How to simplify Z3 input format (such as remove and merge operation) and transfer them to normal bool expressions?

Tags: z3, solidity, simplify

For example, the target program is as following:

```
    pragma solidity >=0.4.24 <0.6.0;
    contract Simple {
        function f(uint a) payable public{
        a += 1;
            if (a == 66 && a+3<100) {
               a = a+3;
            }
        }
    }
```

I got the complicated path constrains expressed by z3 format:

```
(declare-fun TXVALUE () (_ BitVec 256))
(declare-fun a_19 () (_ BitVec 256))(assert (= a_19 #x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001))
(declare-fun a_20 () (_ BitVec 256))(assert (= a_20 (bvadd TXVALUE a_19)))
(declare-fun a_21 () (_ BitVec 256))(assert (= a_21 #x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000042))
(declare-fun a_22 () Bool)(assert (= a_22 (= a_20 a_21)))
(declare-fun a_23 () (_ BitVec 256))(assert (= a_23 #x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001))
(declare-fun a_24 () (_ BitVec 256))(assert (= a_24 #x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000))
(declare-fun a_25 () (_ BitVec 256))(assert (= a_25 (ite a_22 a_23 a_24)))
(declare-fun a_26 () (_ BitVec 256))(assert (= a_26 #x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000))
(declare-fun a_27 () Bool)(assert (= a_27 (= a_25 a_26)))
(declare-fun a_28 () (_ BitVec 256))(assert (= a_28 #x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001))
(declare-fun a_29 () (_ BitVec 256))(assert (= a_29 #x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000))
(declare-fun a_30 () (_ BitVec 256))(assert (= a_30 (ite a_27 a_28 a_29)))
(declare-fun a_31 () (_ BitVec 256))(assert (= a_31 #x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000))
(declare-fun a_32 () Bool)(assert (= a_32 (= a_30 a_31)))
(declare-fun a_33 () (_ BitVec 256))(assert (= a_33 #x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007a))
(declare-fun a_34 () (_ BitVec 256))(assert (= a_34 #x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000072))
(declare-fun a_35 () (_ BitVec 256))(assert (= a_35 (ite (not a_32) a_33 a_34)))
(declare-fun a_36 () (_ BitVec 256))(assert (= a_36 #x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000072))
(assert (= a_35 a_36))
```

There are too many variables. In fact, what I want is: `a+1 ==6 && a+1+3<100`

Is there any way to realize this?

Answer (score 1):

This is really a solidity question, not z3. (Added the appropriate tag.)

In general what you'd consider "simple" and what these tools consider "simple" hardly ever match, and there's no way for you to control that internal form. But perhaps solidity (which I'm not familiar with) itself has some tricks up its sleeve.

Is there a particular task you're trying to achieve, other than being able to see the output in a more human-readable form?

Comment: Regardless of the analyzed Solidity program, my final goal is to transfer z3 formulas in smtlib format to normal bool expressions, so I think this is a z3 question.  Yes, I am doing a task.